# What if I use a boy with its hidden ability and a genderless Pokemon

Tags: pokemon-omega-ruby-alpha-sapphire

OK my krabby is a boy with sheer force and a staryu who hold a everstone and is timid do you think I will get a staryu with its hidden ability?

Answer (score 2):

Nothing will happen. Staru can only breed with Ditto because Staru is in the "genderless" egg group.

If you want to breed Starus with their hidden ability, the parent Staru will need to have it. (It doesn't matter what ability the ditto has). This will make child Staru have the hidden ability sometimes.

This is also the only way to breed male-exclusive pokémon such as Braviary or Hitmonchan.